# Simplify the following expression in $\Bbb Z_4\times S_4$: $([2],(123))^{-1}([1],(24))([2],(123)).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Simplify the following expression in $\Bbb Z_4\times S_4$:
>   $$([2],(123))^{-1}([1],(24))([2],(123)).$$

I believe that I start out finding the inverse of $([2],(123))^{-1}$, which I believe is $([2],(132))$

What would I do next?

Comment: Multiply the result just in each component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In groups of the form $G \times H$,we have
$$(a,b) \star (c,d)=(a \star_{G} c, \,\, b\star_H d),$$
where $\star_G$ and $\star_H$ are binary operations on $G$ and $H$ respectively.

In here we have,
$$\left([b], \tau\right)^{-1}\left([a], \alpha\right)\left([b], \tau\right)=\left([b]^{-1}\star_1 [a] \star_1 [b], \,\,\, \tau^{-1}\alpha \tau\right).$$

Now observe that, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is an abelian group, so $bab^{-1}=a$.

Also in $S_4$, $\tau (abc) \tau^{-1}=(\tau(a) \, \tau(b) \, \tau(c))$

This means
\begin{align*}
\left([2], (123)\right)^{-1}\left([1], (24)\right)\left([2], (123)\right)
&=\left([1], (321)(24)(123)\right)\\
&=\left([1], (14)\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Is the theory necessary to prove the answer or would the calculation part be enough explanation you think?

Comment: @cele Theory is there to help you understand the process so that you can do other problems on your own.

Comment: gotcha. Just looks different from my notes but ill study it